# PDF print server

Tags: pdf, printing, cloud

There are several computers to which we want to connect a server as a printer, and so the server would create a PDF from the print file received from the client.
Unfortunately, we have no choice but to connect as a printer, since the user is still just one user. On the other hand, we have to get a PDF on the server side and then output it so that we can continue working with it there.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a software development question, and is seeking a recommendation.

Comment: I really didn't write about it, but the point is to develop a software, but I don't know what technology to use for the solution, that's why the question was created.